# Code isn't swapping cases as I expect it to

Tags: python, case-sensitive

I wrote some code to swap the cases of a string, but it seems like it's doing it quite inconsistently. I'm hoping some of you could clarify what's wrong. For the record, I'm aware of the `swapcase()` method, but my initial attempt was to test how I'd approach the problem without it. Without further ado:

```
p = "Www.HackerRank.com → wWW.hACKERrANK.COM"
p1 = p.split(" ")
n = []

for i in p1:
    item = list(p1[p1.index(i)])
    for i in item:
        if i.isalpha()==True:
            if i.isupper()==True:
                item[item.index(i)] = i.lower()
            elif i.islower()==True:
                item[item.index(i)] = i.upper()
        else: pass
    n.append(item)

for i in n:
    n[n.index(i)] = "".join(n[n.index(i)])

n = " ".join(n)
```

That's the code. The initial string, `p` is `"Www.HackerRank.com → wWW.hACKERrANK.COM"`. The end result, n however, is `"WWw.hACKErRANK.COM → wwW.HackeRrank.com"`.

So we have:

`"Www.HackerRank.com → wWW.hACKERrANK.COM"` = p

`"WWw.hACKErRANK.COM → wwW.HackeRrank.com"` = n

As you can see, some of the letters are properly converted whilst others aren't. Is it possible to fix the code so that I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to directly loop through the letters of the string instead of splitting it into words first:

```
positive = "Www.HackerRank.com → wWW.hACKERrANK.COM"
negative = []
for letter in positive:
    if letter.isalpha():
        if letter.isupper():
            negative.append(letter.lower())
        else:
            negative.append(letter.upper())
    else:
        negative.append(letter)
        
negative = "".join(negative)
```

Please try to use meaningful names (this makes your life easier when revisiting your own code in a month or two).